# CoreNLPParser: parser.parse issues with dashes(-) and percent signs(%)

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I'm using the `CoreNLPParser()` with NLTK 3.4.5. When I attempt to parse a sentence that contains dashes or percent signs I receive a generic 500 Server Error. This is done after the CoreNLPServer 4.2.2 is started. A `words` list without dashes or percent signs works perfectly.

```py
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser

words = ['-', 'This', 'him', 'with', 'love', 'and', 'keep', 'a', 'good', 'swimming', '-', 'Keep', 'losing', 'the', 'key', 'and', 'not', 'to', 'bite', 'it']
parser = CoreNLPParser()
result = parser.parse(words)
```

I've tried replacing them with periods but then the sentence structure can be ruined if there is a hyphenated word present. I would think NLTK could handle this issue. Is anyone else having this problem? Do I need a different version or something?

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of correct encoding of the web service (http) request between nltk and CoreNLP (% is a special character in URL encoding).

It was fixed in nltk in Feb 2021: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/2661

I just tried this with CoreNLPServer v4.2.0 and nltk-3.6.2 and it worked fine.

You need to upgrade to a newer nltk.